# Commenting current line with shorcut CRTL+/ instead of block commenting

Tags: sublimetext3

When I use the shortcut CTRL+/, without selecting anything, Sublime Text 3 inserts `/**/` where the cursor is in my typescript (*.ts) files, instead of commenting out the current line by inserting `//` at its beginning.

Block commenting should happen only when I selected several lines.

Comment: Sorry, deleted previous comment. What syntax do you use? I'm checking with built-in TypeScript on ST4 (sorry, I don't have ST3 any longer, it's terribly old), and it works as expected (line with the cursor is commented out with `//`). So your solution may be "consider upgrading to ST4" - there may be a deficiency in old unsupported editor version.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.